# while read incredibly slow

Tags: bash, while-loop

As far as I understand, "while read" is so slow, because it reads byte-wise.
Is there a more efficient way to do this if line-wise is sufficient for me?

I have a file data.txt containing four parameters per line:

```
1 56 56 48
3 646 86 656
4 56 894 959
6 89 849 875
```

etc.

and i want to perform an operation on each line (assign each value to a variable for further processing).

this is how i do it now:

```
cat data.txt | 
while read linewise; do
par0=`echo $linewise |awk '{print $1}'`; 
par1=`echo $linewise |awk '{print $2}'`;
par2=`echo $linewise |awk '{print $3}'`;
par3=`echo $linewise |awk '{print $4}'`;

echo $par0 $par1 $par2 $par3
done
```

But for a ~1000 line file this takes half a minute:

```
real    0m30.380s
user    0m7.996s
sys     0m11.820s
```

How can I speed this up?

Comment: The main overhead in this code is calling the external program `awk` four times for every line, not the `read`.   If you have 1000 lines, that's 4000 child processes being created.  You are also calling `cat` unnecessarily, so 4001.  So half a minute is quite good going actually.

Comment: Do you actually need to create these 4 shell variables? What do you plan on doing with them? If you really want it to be quick, you should probably be reading the whole file and doing your processing in a single invocation of awk, avoiding a `while read` loop entirely. Of course, that depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Pretty much any other way of reading the file is going to be quicker than this.

Comment: i'm writing the values in a rrd database and each line has an own database. rrdtool update $par0.rrd N:par1:$par2:$par3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could speed it up by removing all the pipes and calls to subshells. The below greatly simplifies what you're doing:

```
while read -r par0 par1 par2 par3; do 
  echo $par0 $par1 $par2 $par3
done < data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! The whole thing is running now in 0.241s.

Comment: Though simply `awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' data.txt` is probably going to be faster still by a large factor. Avoid `while read` if you can.